# How can I get sweet potato skin to caramelize without baking?

Tags: microwave, caramelization, sweet-potatoes

I love sweet potatoes, and cooking them in the microwave for 8 minutes is much faster than waiting an hour or more for them to bake. But when I microwave them, the skin doesn't caramelize like it does in the oven.

I tried using a kitchen torch on the skin after microwaving, but it started to look more burnt than caramelized.

How can I get the skin to caramelize when cooking a sweet potato in the microwave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A microwave with a grill (broiler) element does this. You need to turn the sweet potatoes over a couple of times to get reasonably even coverage. Better still is a microwave with a combination microwave and convection mode (but these aren't cheap).

If you don't have such a microwave, you can try preheating your grill while the potatoes are cooking and finishing them off there.